# <Server Exception> in run: Failed to parse the incoming object with IO error type 13

Tags: machine-learning, dolphindb

The exception is thrown when running some time-consuming training tasks that read data frequently.

in run: Failed to parse the incoming object with IO error type 13

This occurs when the system is parsing the client requests. What can be done to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered a similar case when using python API. If the script in s.run("scripts") is too long and exceeds the limit, RuntimeError occurs and reports an error. I believe the two situations are very similar and the attached screenshot is for your reference.

[image]